# Does Anaconda reinstall all the packages like(numpy, pandas, pycuda etc) even if I had installed them earlier separately with python in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, anaconda

As I already have quite a lot of packages installed without installing Anaconda will I have to reinstall them again separately? Or are they accessible in Anaconda environment because I have them preinstalled? There is a similar question which has the answer suggesting installing only miniconda but in my case Anaconda is necessary.

Comment: Installing Anaconda installs its own version of Python. You will not have access to packages you installed in another Python install on your system.

Answer (score 0):

No, anaconda uses completely different environments and whatever downgrading it does, it does it within it's own environments. So, if you are using anaconda environments within your applications, you don't need to reinstall anything but if you are using another environment (like pip only) you need to make sure you have installed all the necessary packages there as well.
Also, if a package is installed using pip and not installed in conda, it will automatically switch to pip so there is no problem there.